# MSE chat not allow me to participate

Tags: support, chat

When I go through this [link](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=drupal&Room=89&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) I'm not able to login with chat see the screenshot and I tried hard refresh also. Right now I have 976 rep.

> [image]

Comment: Have you tried logging in?

Comment: @JanDvorak not sure where to find the login in that page

Comment: Why were you searching in the transcript if you wanted to join the chat room? Click room name and join.

Comment: @InfiniteSnowflakes whatever it is, it need to allow me to enter and I found the link here http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3146/winter-bash-2014#comment4435_3147 and more over it says you need 20 rep to chat, now what ?

Comment: @Bala just a misunderstanding. As Behaviour already answered, that's only a search result, not the chat room itself. The message itself sometimes appears to everyone, for SE's only knows (blame caching).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you followed is a search link, so it shows you the parts of chat transcript where the term was found. If you dismiss the notification bar covering the top of the screen, you should be able to see the search boxes followed by "in room [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta)". The room name is a link to the room itself.